# Using regex to find multiple matches on the same line

Tags: python, regex

I need to build a program that can read multiple lines of code, and extract the right information from each line.
Example text:

```
no matches
one match <'found'>
<'one'> match <found>
<'three'><'matches'><'found'>
```

For this case, the program should detect `<'found'>`, `<'one'>`, `<'three'>`, `<'matches'>` and `<'found'>` as matches because they all have "<" and "`'`".
However, I cannot work out a system using regex to account for multiple matches on the same line. I was using something like:

```
re.search('^<.*>$')
```

But if there are multiple matches on one line, the extra "`'<`" and "`>'`" are taken as part of the `.*`, without counting them as separate matches. How do I fix this?

Comment: The multiple match problem is taken care of by removing the anchors and making the dot quantifier lazy (non-greedy).  But you also need to add the single quote to your pattern -- see anubhava's regex pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works -

```
>>> r = re.compile(r"\<\'.*?\'\>")
>>> r.findall(s)
["<'found'>", "<'one'>", "<'three'>", "<'matches'>", "<'found'>"]
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `<`, `'`, `>`. They just matches literally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and match on non `>` characters inside of the angle brackets:

```
>>> re.findall('<[^>]*>', "<'three'><'matches'><'found'>")
["<'three'>", "<'matches'>", "<'found'>"]
```

Non-greedy quantifier '?' as suggested by anubhava is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

Use `findall` instead of `search`:

```
re.findall( r"<'.*?'>", str )
```